# What beer is vegan?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan

What beer is considered vegan, and why? Is it about yeast, gelatin or some other ingredients?

In other words, what are the key ingredients in beer which makes it non-vegan (so they can be avoided specifically)?

I'm not asking for [vegetarian alcohol alternatives](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/33/2), but specifically when beer is considered vegan.

Comment: I've seen it, but the question doesn't mention 'vegan' specifically, secondly it sounds like it's asking for wine/beer alternatives. ('What is the vegetarian alternative to this?')

Comment: It's asking for an alternative filtering agent instead of isinglass (rather than an alternative booze) -- but I see your point.

Comment: I understood this question as _I know why some beers are not vegan, but how do I identify them?_ Depending on local regulations, companies might not be obligated to disclose their process inputs in the package if they are not an actual ingredient.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spirits, wine and beers are all plant-based, however beer and wine are sometimes processed using animal by-products (egg, gelatin, casein, glycerin, or isinglass) used as a fining agent for settling out suspended matter in the vat.

Generally, British beers use isinglass, gelatin, glycerin or casein. German and Belgium beers using traditional methods of brewing are vegan.

Barnivore.com has an [amazing database of beer brands](http://www.barnivore.com/beer) labeling which are vegan, mostly vegan and not vegan:

Comment: Germany has pretty strict laws on what can be called a beer (as opposed to a beer-based beverage), so german beer is generally considered vegan because most non vegan ingredients or processes would be against the law :)